# Starting with postgres for beginners

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I am trying to make a website using ruby bricks (using MAC), since I am quite new on web development. I quickly generated a template application, however it did not work as it was looking for a postgres database running in the background.

I have Java/C like background, thus I honestly have no idea what is going on. I just know the basic database commands such as WHERE GROUP BY etc, and the main idea.

So I downloaded pgAdmin3, hoping that the user interface would make it easier. Still I couldn't find my way out. For now, I have the following error when I do 'rails server' on one terminal, and 'postgres -D /usr/local/psql/data' on another.

```
FATAL: role "mike" does not exist
```

(I think I created a database at /usr/local/psql/data, without being aware, I just copied a code I found online to see if it would work, before that I was receiving 'couldnt connect to server error' since there was no database running.)

From the following links, I figured that I have to create a role. But I dont know where to write 'create role mike'.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-createdb.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/database-roles.html

I would really appreciate if you could tell me about where I write the commands, where I see databases, roles etc. and modify them. I want to believe it is easier than it seems, even for a beginner.

Comment: I'm hitting this on Linux and I don't know whether this applies on a Mac: attempting to connect to the PostgreSQL server using *Unix domain socket* uses **peer authentication**, which assumes the user has the same name in the database as is his name in the OS: no password confirmation necessary since the OS itself confirms identity. [Look here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for configuration documentation.

Comment: How did you install PostgreSQL? From where?

Comment: I used `brew install postgresql` and I had those errors. Postgresapp seems to work however.

Answer (score 0):

> FATAL: role "mike" does not exist

This is very common error.You need to do below steps to overcome it.

1. `sudo -u postgres psql`
2. Now create the user you specified in `config/database.yml`'s development section:

   `CREATE ROLE your_user_name WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'your_password'`

Comment: for `sudo su postgres` , i get `su: unknown login: postgres`

Comment: `sudo postgres` gives `root execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted. `

Comment: @OE1 Try giving `psql -U postgres` instead

Comment: now i get `could not connect to server: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the command line, you'll need to create the role using psql. If you're just starting postgresql, there's a little trick involved with this. Postgresql starts with only the postgres user initialized. You have to add other users from the postgres user login.

This is how I do it on a new installation.

From the root user: (assuming linux)

```
su postgres 
psql
create user <your user name> superuser ;
\q
exit
```

Now you can use psql with your regular user ID.

Answer (score 0):

Simply moving to
http://postgresapp.com/
got around the error messages. +I have a visual interface as I wanted. Thanks for the suggestions, hope this helps other beginners as well.